# My dead keys are inserting double characters when typed

Tags: keyboard, windows-11, dead-keys

I'm running **Windows 11 Home 64-bit, OS Build 22000.2057 and it's on version 21H2.**
The German keyboard has two dead keys and they work great on my friends' computer. But when I try to use them on my laptop, instead of me typing **"^"** and then **"a"** (which should insert **"â"**), the computer just inserts **"^^"**. Similarly, **"´´"** is inserted instead of just a single **"´"**.

I have restarted my laptop, which of course didn't help. I am considering reverting back to Window 10 but I think it's too risky. If anyone could help me troubleshoot this I would be very glad.

Comment: Both instances of Windows is set to the same locale and have the same language packs installed? Its very doubtful this has anything to do with Windows 11 directly and more likely easily solved by changing the locale of the system or reinstalling the language pack itself

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a Dell Latitude 5520 notebook running Windows 11 Enterprise 23H2 build 22631.3007. The problem appeared after installation of Dell Display Manager. It disappeared after uninstalling Dell Display Manager again. So at least in my case, the confirmed cause of the problem was Dell Display Manager.